# Java: Control browser through Process

Tags: java, google-chrome, process, subprocess

I'm remote controlling a Java application on a PC through an Android phone, and I needed my application to open a browser at the phones command, chrome in this case. I created a "Process" for chrome, opening a certain address. However, I need to be able to give tools on the Android phone for controlling the web page, such as scrolling. Can I programmatically send a command for chrome to scroll from my PC application containing the Process?

Sorry, it may have been unclear, but the only connection the android phone has to the program is through a socket. It is only used as a remote control for another Java application on a PC, which has its own screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that clean solution exists.

But I can suggest the following directions:

(1) try to investigate the native chrome API. If it has such ability call it with JNI.

(2) Try to use class `java.awt.Robot`. It allows to simulate user's activity, e.g. mouse clicks. Unfortunately it does not allow you to find any window outside your application, so it is a problem to decide where to perform the click.

(3) You can create proxy server and make browser you open to go to the target URL through the proxy. The proxy server will insert into the page your javascript that will communicate with server. The application that opens browser will send commands to server. The javascript that you inserted will receive these commands using AJAX and perform them. JavaScript can scroll browser window, so theoretically you can implement this.

Answer (score 2):

If you can target the tab you want to control and edit the address bar you could send the command 'javascript:scrollTo(x, y)'.  I just tested it on this page and it seems to work fine, replacing what I typed with the original address of the page.

Comment: I have it as a Process in a java program, is it possible to send such a command to it through that?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I programmatically send a command for chrome to scroll from my PC
>   application containing the Process?

Not directly. What you could do is make some sort of web service that sits between the Android client and page that the Android client can send commands to and the page can periodically poll via AJAX calls to see what the client wants. That would be a clean DIY way that would work on other browsers besides Chrome.

Comment: Ok, i'll see if I can find some other way, otherwise i'll look into this, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vnc viewer applications for that.

http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/